# postgresql do not aggregate by my timestamp

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have sql like following:

```
with CTE as (
select user_id,level,plugged,plugged_ac,plugged_usb,created_at from probe_batteries where          probe_batteries.user_id='91' and probe_batteries.created_at > timestamp '2014-06-07 17:00:00'
and probe_batteries.created_at < timestamp '2014-06-07 23:00:00'
) 
select CTE.user_id as user_id, avg(CTE.level), bool_or(CTE.plugged), bool_or(CTE.plugged_ac), bool_or(CTE.plugged_usb),date_trunc('second',CTE.created_at) as created_at
from CTE
group by created_at, user_id
order by created_at asc
```

but the table result do not aggregate according the created_at (see the last column in the results) which is timestamp type

```
91;95.0000000000000000;f;f;f;"2014-06-07 20:46:06"
91;95.0000000000000000;f;f;f;"2014-06-07 21:19:11"
91;95.0000000000000000;f;f;f;"2014-06-07 21:19:12"
91;95.0000000000000000;f;f;f;"2014-06-07 21:19:12"
91;95.0000000000000000;f;f;f;"2014-06-07 21:19:12"
91;95.0000000000000000;f;f;f;"2014-06-07 21:19:13"
91;95.0000000000000000;f;f;f;"2014-06-07 21:19:13"
91;95.0000000000000000;f;f;f;"2014-06-07 21:19:13"
91;95.0000000000000000;f;f;f;"2014-06-07 21:19:14"
```

Is there anything wrong with my sql sentence? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have expression alias `created_at` matching column name of your `CTE` named subquery.

Try giving another alias instead, like:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT user_id,level,plugged,plugged_ac,plugged_usb,created_at
    FROM probe_batteries
   WHERE user_id='91' AND created_at > timestamp '2014-06-07 17:00:00'
     AND created_at < timestamp '2014-06-07 23:00:00'
) 
SELECT CTE.user_id as user_id, avg(CTE.level), bool_or(CTE.plugged),
       bool_or(CTE.plugged_ac), bool_or(CTE.plugged_usb),
       date_trunc('second',CTE.created_at) AS dt_at
  FROM CTE
 GROUP BY dt_at, user_id
 ORDER BY dt_at ASC;
```